# What statistic test would you reccomend for binary data?

Tags: statistical-significance, binary-data

I have a data including 100 samples as controls and 100 samples with disease. I was testing those samples for patogenity of 3 bacteria. The results looks like below: 1-yes, 0-no.

```
> Sample disease Bacteria1 Bacteria2 Bacteria3 
s1 1 0 1 
s2 1 1 1 
s3 1 0 1
s4 0 0 1 ...
```

The same data for 100 control samples including only 0.

I see the difference but I ma not sure which test could I use to statistically prove it.

I need to show that test that I've validated and results are statistically significant and that it can be used to detect those bacteria in human samples.

I will be glad for any suggestion.

Comment: Did you try logistic regression? That would be my departure point!

Comment: It seems like you are using R.  What is the purpose of the modelling, what question do you want to solve using the data?  There are a lot of posts on this site about logistic regression, you could start by browsing those!

Comment: My question would be: Is there a significant difference between disease and control groups in case of occurrence of bacteria1, bacteria2 and bacteria3...

Comment: And the bacteria$i $ variables are just presence(1)/absence(0)?

Comment: Yes. It is presence(1)/absence(0)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion about logistic regression. It fits well to my experiment :) Best, Agata